# Implementing SJF Scheduling Algorithm in MINIX 3.2.1

Tags: c, process, operating-system, scheduling, minix

I'm currently working on a project for an Operating Systems course at university

Implementing an SJF Scheduling Algorithm is required instead of the current MINIX 3.2.1 default scheduling algorithm.
I'm having difficulty finding resources on the internet due to Minix being outdated.

Any idea on how to implement such an algorithm?

I tried to change the source code inside sched and pm directories with no luck in implementing the algorithm successfully.

Comment: Step 1 - First we need to understand and implement the SJF algorithm as general implementation (e.g. how to select and dispatch a process from the ready queue). This can be done by creating a simple simulation program to simulate the SJF. Step 2 we need to get the reference to study how Minix implement the scheduler and the components involved. Then implement the SJF algorithm in Minix.